# Using LinkedIn API with Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I am trying to use LinkedIn API for getting user logged in to our system based on google app engine. I am using ozgur/python-linkedin library for implementing it.

Now so far I am getting able to `print authentication.authorization_url`, and obtain the `authentication.authorization_code`.

```
 authentication = linkedin.LinkedInAuthentication(API_KEY, API_SECRET, RETURN_URL, linkedin.PERMISSIONS.enums.values())
 print authentication.authorization_url  # open this url on your browser
 application = linkedin.LinkedInApplication(authentication)
 authentication.authorization_code = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
 authentication.get_access_token()
```

Now once I call `get_access_token` method I am getting this error:

> ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.linkedin.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /uas/oauth2/accessToken (Caused by : [Errno 13] Permission denied)

Comment: I too use linkedin to log in with gae but I do it with simpleauth. It works pretty good with simpleauth and if you still have problems with ozgur/python-linkedin then you might want to try simpleauth for gae logins.

Comment: I am looking simpleauth, can you just quickly tell me how to get the arguments(data, auth_info, provider) in _on_signin method?

Comment: Yes, you map it with webapp2 like `/auth/<provider>` and then you can make a request like `/auth/linkedin` to your app. You might need some more adjustments, if so you look in the authhandler for simpleauth. It can also authenticate via Facebook and Foursquare so I think it is pretty good. If you have problems with simpleauth then please post a new question and we can help you more there.

Comment: Do I need any permission from LinkedIn to get email id of user who signs in to my system? Kindly reply soon :)