# Using simpleauth to login in with GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, authentication, linkedin-api

This question is in the reference of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30077303/using-linkedin-api-with-python). As suggested I am using `simpleaut`h to login via linkedin. Now I am having trouble with the `redirect_uri`. I have successfully deployed **dev_appserver.py example/** but when I click on LinkedIn Oauth2, I get this error.

```
 invalid redirect_uri. This value must match a URL registered with the API Key.
```

My redirect uri from url:

```
redirect_uri= http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fauth%2Flinkedin2%2Fcallback
```

And I have entered same redirect url(http://localhost:8080/auth/linkedin/callback) in https://www.linkedin.com/developer/ page.

I was already stuck with previous library, and even this doesn't seems to work for me now.

Comment: You must register your app with linkedin and get an APi key there. Please see this link how to register your app and get the parameters https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2

Comment: I have already done that. I am confused with what to put in 
OAuth 2.0 Authorized Redirect URLs: ?
RIght now I am putting http://localhost:8080

Comment: Now it's working. This http://localhost:8080/auth/linkedin2/callback is the correct url. Thanks for reply.

Comment: Very good! I have a slightly different setup. I use only /auth/linkedin. You may have a look a my setup if you like http://www.koolbusiness.com/login/

Comment: Looks good, few questions. Do you get the email id of user signed in via linkedin? Also don't you use oauth2 library for authentication?

Answer (score 1):

Request url should be http://localhost:8080/auth/linkedin2/callback. Now it's working.